# Dajngo- Error Field 'id' expected a number but got string

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

There is a table like this:

```
+---+----+-------+------+
|   | id | color | type |
+---+----+-------+------+
| 1 | 1  | Blue  | 2    |
+---+----+-------+------+
| 2 | 2  | Green | 4    |
+---+----+-------+------+
| 3 | 3  | White | 5    |
+---+----+-------+------+
| 4 | 4  | Red   | 6    |
+---+----+-------+------+
| 5 | 5  | Gray  | 8    |
+---+----+-------+------+
```

In template, there are two fields to do search in this table. One field for searching for *color* that is a string, and the other for *type* that is a number.

In views.py I have this filter:

```
results = models.MyModel.objects.filter(Q(color__iexact=search_query) | Q(type=search_query))
```

If I search for a number it shows some results, while searching for a string results in error as below:

> ValueError at /search/
>
> Field 'id' expected a number but got 'White'.

What should I do to correct it?

Comment: please show the full code. view, form and model

Comment: there might be something in forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's because your `type` field is an `int` and you are trying to query it with a `str`, what you should do is define a seperate **input** for a `type` field, grab the value and then query it:

```
color_search_query = request.POST.get('color_search_query')
id_search_query = request.POST.get('id_search_query')
results = models.MyModel.objects.all()
if color_search_query:
    results = results.filter(color__iexact=color_search_query) 
if id_search_query:
    results = results.filter(type=id_search_query)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is correct and your method works very well.